# How to backport Android 4.0's switch button to Honeycomb and earlier

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, togglebutton, backport

I want to use the Switch toggle button (on/off) of Android 4.0 in Android 3.0. I would like to know there is any supported library for it. I have tried to copy the source code of `android.widget.Switch` from ICS, with no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A quick google search revealed this two libraries:

- https://github.com/ankri/SwitchCompatLibrary
- https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport

I have no experience using either of them, but the latter one seems to have a sample on the [Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.sample) with the following screenshot (image taken from the app's page):

[image]